# How to generate robotium test reports with spoon?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium, spoon, android-instrumentation

I am using robotium and spoon together, spoon generates the result in nice html with screenshots and log, but what **I am trying to do is towards the end of the test I have some more checks to do in my application like checking file is created on the phone or not based on that I want to declare the test result pass/fail**, I want to include this result into Spoon report because there are multiple device connected, doing this in all the devices is quite challenging.
**Just writing log which is collected by spoon is not the best way because every time in the report I have to check log manually to ensure that test is passed/failed.**

What is the best way to include my custom result to spoon result?
Any kind of help is appriciated, thanks in advance.
P.S:- Long text paragraph on stack overflow? sry

Answer (score -1):

You can import the spoon jar in `build.gradle`.

```
compile files('libs/spoon-client-1.1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/spoon-runner-1.1.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
```

Then use

```
Spoon.screenshot(activity, "Screenshotname");
```

Comment: I have already included spoon, your answer is completely different from what i have asked.